# Apportable app crash during execution ( iOS app converted to Android)

Tags: android, ios, crash, apportable

I am running my converted iOS to android app with following command "apportable debug" because the app crashes at startup when running on the device.
I see the following printout anyone who can help me understand what is happening? : 
Continuing.

> ```
> [New Thread 25347]
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> [Switching to Thread 25347]
> 0x55922a48 in __30_2B__5B_VerdeActivity_20_verdeActivity_5D__block_invoke () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/EasyRunner/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so
> (gdb) backtrace
> #0  0x55922a48 in __30_2B__5B_VerdeActivity_20_verdeActivity_5D__block_invoke () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/EasyRunner/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so
> #1  0x51960d90 in dispatch_once_f () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libdispatch.so
> #2  0x51960ce8 in dispatch_once () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libdispatch.so
> #3  0x55922814 in _2B__5B_VerdeActivity_20_verdeActivity_5D_ () from
> ```
>
> /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/EasyRunner/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so
>       #4  0x558c2a4c in *2D*_5B_MixpanelAPI_20_track_3A_properties_3A_*5D* () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/EasyRunner/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so
>       #5  0x5591f1f0 in android_exceptionHandler () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/EasyRunner/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so
>       #6  0x548a3938 in callUncaughtHandler () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libFoundation.so
>       #7  0x548a4380 in *2D*_5B_NSException_20_raise_5D_ () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libFoundation.so
>       #8  0x548a3bb0 in *2B*_5B_NSException_20_raise_3A_format_3A_arguments_3A_*5D* () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libFoundation.so
>       #9  0x548a3b38 in *2B*_5B_NSException_20_raise_3A_format_3A_*5D* () from
>   /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libFoundation.so
>       #10 0x5482f5e0 in *2D*_5B_GSMutableArray_20_addObject_3A_*5D* () from
>   /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libFoundation.so
>       #11 0x5589e8b4 in *2D*_5B__XibNode_20_addChild_3A_*5D* () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/EasyRunner/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so
>       #12 0x55894aa0 in *2D*_5B_UINibCoder_20_parser_3A_didStartElement_3A_namespaceURI_3A_qualifiedName_3A_attributes_3A_*5D*
>   () from
>   /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/EasyRunner/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so
>       #13 0x5494e67c in *2D*_5B_NSXMLParser_20_didStartElement_5D_ () from
>   /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libFoundation.so
>       #14 0x5494f170 in *2D*_5B_NSXMLParser_20_parse_5D_ () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libFoundation.so
>       #15 0x55894480 in *2D*_5B_UINibCoder_20_initForReadingWithData_3A_bundle_3A_*5D* () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/EasyRunner/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so
>       #16 0x55893428 in *2D*_5B_UINib_20_initWithData_3A_bundle_3A_*5D* () from
>   /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/EasyRunner/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so
>       #17 0x55893908 in *2B*_5B_UINib_20_nibWithPath_3A_bundle_3A_*5D* () from
>   /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/EasyRunner/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so
>       #18 0x5589335c in __19_2B__5B_UINib_20_initialize_5D__block_invoke () from
>   /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/EasyRunner/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so
>       #19 0x5195b58c in _dispatch_call_block_and_release () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libdispatch.so
>       #20 0x51964aa0 in _dispatch_worker_thread2 () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libdispatch.so
>       #21 0x518cc19c in worker_main () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libpthread_workqueue.so
>       #22 0x53e1a074 in thread_start () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/SDK/sysroot/android/armeabi/usr/lib/libv.so
>       #23 0x40165f4c in __thread_entry () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/cache/devices/HT2CJTP03815/libs/libc.so
>       #24 0x40165654 in pthread_create () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/cache/devices/HT2CJTP03815/libs/libc.so
>       #25 0x00000000 in ?? () from /Users/peterbodlund/.apportable/cache/devices/HT2CJTP03815/libs/linker

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there might be a element not being decoded properly in your xib; if you could send a copy of that to us we should be able to fix that. Our support email address is support@apportable.com